# UIView animation duration

Tags: ios, animation

I have an UIView and I want to change it's background color. That works well using the `UIView beginAnimation:context:` method. However, the animation 'lasts' for like 1 second or so. I want it to last 5 seconds. This is the code I'm using:

```
- (void)updateSky:(NSString *)time {
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"backgroundUpdate" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 5.0];

    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0x63/255.0f green:0xA9/255.0f blue:0xFF/255.0f alpha:1.0] CGColor],
                                                 (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0x8C/255.0f green:0xBF/255.0f blue:0xFF/255.0f alpha:1.0] CGColor], nil];

    if(time == @"night") {
        gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0x1E/255.0f green:0x1E/255.0f blue:0x1E/255.0f alpha:1.0] CGColor],
                                                     (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0x2C/255.0f green:0x4C/255.0f blue:0x72/255.0f alpha:1.0] CGColor], nil];
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

`gradient` is defined as follows:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient;
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to animate setting a UIView's background color using view animation is to set its `backgroundColor` property. You don't seem to be doing that. What is this thing `gradient` and what is its `colors` property? The problem here seems to be that you're using UIView animation, but `colors` is not a UIView animatable property so this makes no sense. You need to provide more code to show what you're really doing. For example, if this is an implicit layer animation you'd use `+[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:]` to set the duration.

(Also this whole `beginAnimations` / `commitAnimations` structure, while not exactly deprecated, is virtually on the chopping block. That's irrelevant to your question, but it would be good to get out of it if you can, just on principle. You should be using `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`, or implicit layer animation, or explicit Core Animation.)

Comment: I've updated the question. You mentioned `[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:]`, I think that'll work. I'm going to take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: The question still makes no sense as posed. A CAGradientLayer is not a UIView, so you can't use UIView animation with it. It's a layer so you have to use layer animation. If this is not a view's main layer, you may be accidentally doing implicit layer animation; in that case, CATransaction is the way to go. But if that's true, you should be able to get rid of all that UIView stuff and the animation would still work. Otherwise, you're probably headed for Core Animation, and there's nothing wrong with that. You might want to read my chapter on this topic: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html

Comment: CATransaction indeed worked. Thanks for your answer. I also got rid of the UIView animation stuff, CATransaction did the trick :-)

Comment: Excellent! And my book explains *why*. :)